# Disqus API - unable to use 'query' param in 'posts/list'

Tags: permissions, disqus

I have created an Application that has the default access set to "Read, Write and Manage forums" however when I hit the API using **GET forum=our-forum&query=querystring** I'm then returned an error:

```
Uncaught DisqusAPIError: Must have moderator permission on forum our-forum to use 'query' param
```

How else do you set moderator permission for an application?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For those that are looking for the answer to this - pass the access token along with the request:
**GET forum=our-forum&query=querystring&access_token=your-access-token**